# Control KDE application GUIs using d-bus

Tags: kde, dbus

Is there a way to control application windows on Kubuntu/KDE using DBus? I think of raising, maximizing, minimizing, etc. windows of applications started in KDE.

I guess there could be some generic interface that provides these operations but I could not find much information.

Comment: One good place to start is with a dbus browser like `d-feet` (provided by the 'd-feet' package), so you can see what interfaces are available.

Comment: That's what I did. But the tree is huge and I couldn't find what I need.